# Showing "The Visual Studio cache is out of date" when click new query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

I use SQL Server 2016 Management Studio. After I connect to the server and click on "new query", a message appears:

> The Visual Studio cache is out of date

Screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you google "The Visual Studio cache is out of date"?

Comment: SSMS uses the Visual Studio 2015 Isolated shell. Try to install the last version of ssms(currently 16.4.1), I find this bug is still active in https://connect.microsoft.com, you can open ticket if still exist after upgrade  ssms.

Comment: Upgrading to 16.4.1 worked for me

Comment: Restarting my PC did the job for me. Not getting the above error now. I have VS 2015 Enterprise, SQL SERVER 2012, SSMS 2016. Try it! Worked for me :)

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar issue but restarting SSMS(SQL Server 2016 Management Studio) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

you need to delete the windows 'SSMS' temp folder :
C:\Users\your_user_name_here\AppData\Local\Temp\

dont worry, when you run the SSMS again, it will create a new SSMS temp folder for logs.